# Bluetooth drivers fail to install pairing my Samsung phone

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm currently working on an Android application based on Bluetooth Chat sample. The code seems to work but when I try to pair my android device (a Samsung Ace [GT-S5839i](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/smartphone/GT-S5830OKATGY-spec)) with my laptop, some drivers fail to install.
In the device bluetooth services list I can see BluetoothChatSecure and BluetoothChatInsecure services but when I try to connect my phone to my laptop I have a connection error.

This is my first time doing any Bluetooth development, and I can't figure out what happens.

**EDIT:**

Actually I have several errors:

```
08-11 01:34:49.140: E/BluetoothChat(29847): + ON RESUME +
08-11 01:34:49.187: E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(1510): onCreateDeviceResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists (Device already exists)
08-11 01:34:49.203: E/DTUN_HCID4(29886): No device pointer found for peer! Ignore Error = true. Ignoring error...
08-11 01:34:49.421: E/(29869): ****************search UUID = 87fa***********
08-11 01:34:50.179: E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(1510): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/29886/hci0/dev_70_F1_A1_B7_61_A8
08-11 01:34:54.304: E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(1510): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/29886/hci0/dev_70_F1_A1_B7_61_A8
```

**P.S.**

Does anybody know why Windows tried to install two Bluetooth Peripheral Device without finding the right drivers when I used the default uuid?

Comment: Care to share the error message that you're receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally  set up a bluetooth secure connection between my phone and my laptop. These are the required steps:

- First, I set up a Bluetooth Icoming COM port in my laptop
- Secondly, I changed my uuid according to the [android documentation][2]

> ```
> Hint: If you are connecting to a Bluetooth serial board then try using the well-known SPP UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB.
> ```

- Then I enabled the SSP service in my phone so I was able to get the
  Standard Serial over Bluetooth link working
- Finally, I open a serial connection with the Icoming COM port through
  a Hyperterminal (like putty)

I hope this is helpful to someone.